# How to bend the pitch of a source file in Android?

Tags: java, android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I have a source file of a piano sound and I want to dynamically bend the pitch of that file in Android (Java). Any idea on how to do that? What libraries to use?

Thanks

Comment: Define "bend the pitch".

Comment: Changing the pitch of the note basically, like making a C become a D or something in between,

Answer (score 0):

You can first take a look at [TarsosDSP](https://github.com/JorenSix/TarsosDSP). There is an example for "Pitch Shifting" included, which works with mono wave files. For other audio formats you also need to understand the javax.sound.sampled.spi package of the standard API. There are some SPIs for mp3, ogg vorbis out there.

Comment: I'm *pretty* sue the Java Sound API is not included in Android. Also you seem to be referring to support for extra sound formats, not pitch bending. That's theoretically possible in the API, but you'd basically need to access the raw sound frames and do it yourself.